# How to mock/stub callback function with sinon.js?

Tags: javascript, qunit, sinon

I want to write unit tests with QUnit and Sinon.Js. I have an application, where the user can click on a button and a modal dialog appers to handle downloading some files. The user can close the dialog and it triggers a method to run to reset some variables. My test code:

```
$(function() {
    $.fn.copy_button = function(){};

    ln_download_view = new DownloadModalView();
    ln_download_view.modal = {'modal': function() {}};
    var download_modal_dialog = $('.download-modal');
    download_modal_dialog.modal = function(param){};
    var modal_mock = sinon.mock(ln_download_view.modal);
    var download_modal_dialog_mock = sinon.mock(download_modal_dialog);

    //Should be inserted, because ln_download_view.modal is mocked
    //The close button even handler
    $('#btn_close_modal').click(function(){
        download_modal_dialog.modal('hide');
    });

    //Dirty stuff to do after the window closes
    //Basicly the click triggers this event handler
    $('.download-modal').on('hide',function() {
        window.clearInterval(window.periodicalTimer);
    });

    $('div .option-container').click(function() {
        if(!$(this).hasClass("selected-option"))
        {
            $('div #option-presenting').toggleClass("selected-option");
            $('div #option-editing-and-presenting').toggleClass("selected-option");

            $('.image').toggle();
        }
    });

    module("views");
    test("Download modal dialog is displayed", function(){
        var modal_triggered = modal_mock.expects("modal").once();
        ln_download_view.handleDownloadClick();
        ok(modal_triggered.verify());
    });

    test("Download modal dialog is closed",function(){
        var modal_triggered = download_modal_dialog_mock.expects("modal");
        $('#btn_close_modal').trigger('click');
        ok(modal_triggered.verify());
    });
});
```

What I do not understand is, how can I test/mock/stub this piece of code:

```
$('.download-modal').on('hide',function() {
    window.clearInterval(window.periodicalTimer);
});
```

I do not have the deep understanding yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't mock/stub an anonymous function. But you can make a refactoring and stub/mock the named callback.

```
$('.download-modal').on('hide', onHide);

var onHide = function() {
    window.clearInterval(window.periodicalTimer);
};

// ...

sinon.stub(onHide);
```

Comment: Oh, I see. One more thing. When the click happens, right after the on hide should be called to. My test should expect two function call, one to modal, and one to the onHide, but the modal should trigger the onHide. But because the modal is mocked, it is not working. Is it good to overwrite the download_modal_dialog.modal to be equal with a function, which calls onHide? Thank you!

Comment: Then use `sinon.spy`, so it will work as expected + spy that it's calleed.

Comment: Thanks, I made it. But one more question? What is the difference between call onHide() and call on_hide_spy.call(). (var on_hide_spy = sinon.spy(onHide);)

Comment: `.call` just allows you to call the function in particular context. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: The above does not work anymore with Sinon 2.3.8

    `var a = function() {};
    var spy = si.spy(this, a);`

Throws:

    `TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property function () {} as function`

Answer (score 2):

Here's my method for this:

In your before each, make a function that doesn't do anything:

```
var doNothing = function(){};
```

Then in your test, spy on that:

```
var spy = sinon.spy(this, 'doNothing');
```

Then call your method, passing in a callback that fires the doNothing method:

```
  var self = this;
  whatever.doSomethingAwesome(
  {
    finished: function(){
      self.doNothing();
    }
  });
  expect(spy.callCount).toEqual(1);
```